# coalesce alternative in Access SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

In T-SQL, you can do this:

```
SELECT ProductId, COALESCE(Price, 0)
FROM Products
```

How do you do the same thing in Access SQL?  I see examples for doing it with Nz in VBA, but I'm looking for the SQL equivalent.

Thanks.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Access supports the `Nz` function and allows you to use it in a query.  Note though that `Nz` is the same as the T-SQL `ISNULL` function.  It can not take an arbitrary number of parameters like `COALESCE` can.

Comment: "Jet (the database engine behind Access) SQL also supports the Nz function" - Incorrect, Jet has no NZ() function. The MS Access object model has a NZ() function which can be used in queries only within the MS Access interface. Using NZ() outside of the MS Access interface causes an error.

Comment: For some reason NZ([Field], 0) changed the type of the field (left aligned in result set) while IIF ([Price] is null, 0, [Price]) was working well.

Comment: FYI:  The newer ACE database engine (replacement for older Jet engine) _does_ support some VBA functions natively, including Nz().  I think that corresponds to Access 2010 and later. This is primarily necessary because the ACE engine supports Data Macros (similar to triggers in other SQL DBMS) which are supported directly, even outside the Access environment.  The benefit is that such functions are also available in SQL queries.

Comment: @CPerkins, I have ACE 2010 with pyODBC and I'm getting "[Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Undefined function 'NZ' in expression".

Comment: @CristianCiupitu  Although ODBC will often pass SQL directly to the engine, I am aware that it sometimes does its own parsing and analysis. The ACE engine should support it, but the ODBC driver might be preventing it from being passed to the engine if its trying to validate the functions, etc.  Can you share the full SQL statement or at least a snippet showing how it's being called?  Is it properly formatted with correct parameters?  Can you execute the exact same statement from within Access?

Comment: @CPerkins, the query is something like `SELECT NZ(SUM(price * quantity), 0) FROM outputs;`. If I remove the `NZ` call it works fine. I don't have MS Access, just the driver.

Comment: @CristianCiupitu  I verified that Nz() is **not allowed** using various ODBC clients :(. But I also verified that Nz() is recognized by the ACE engine in other contexts. Consider that I get various error messages when using ODBC with calls to functions like DatePart() and Now(), but I still get valid data back. But if I try executing composite calls, ODBC complains and doesn't allow it even though it is perfectly good SQL format and the functions are allowed individually. In summary, nz() is indeed not supported but only because ODBC disallows it being passed to the engine by its own rules.

Answer (score 26):

If it's in an Access query, you can try this:

```
"Price = IIf([Price] Is Null,0,[Price])"
```

Comment: Why not `IIf(IsNull(Price), 0, Price)`?

Comment: How would you use this in the query?

Comment: @David-W-Fenton: because `IsNull()` is VBA and slows down thinks a lot, while `Is Null` is natively handled by Jet & co, See link to Allen Browne's page in my answer.

Comment: To clear up for future readers. [**`IsNull`**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/isnull-function-f963233b-1c1e-4b0c-8bc3-3e8c0ea67c61) is part of MS Access SQL. (not just VBA). You can use this function in backend ODBC/OLEDB queries unlike `NZ`.

Answer (score 9):

Looks like I can just use:

```
SELECT ProductId, Nz(Price, 0)
FROM Products
```

Seems to be working just fine.

Comment: You do need to be careful about the resulting data type of the argument, as it doesn't always end up numeric when you expect it to. I've never quite figured out a pattern of why, though theoretically, it's supposed to pick up the data type of the first argument.

Comment: Also, be careful about using VBA functions in queries, they can be performance killers.

Answer (score 9):

Using `Iif(Price is null, 0, Price)` should give you the best performance (see [Allen Browne's performance tips](http://allenbrowne.com/QueryPerfIssue.html)). However SQL Server `Coalesce()` has the great advantage over `Iif()` and `Nz()` that it can handle several parameters in a cascade.  So I created this quick VBA equivalent:

```
Function Coalesce(ParamArray varValues()) As Variant
'returns the first non null value, similar to SQL Server Coalesce() function
'Patrick Honorez --- www.idevlop.com
    Dim i As Long
    Coalesce = Null
    For i = LBound(varValues) To UBound(varValues)
        If Not IsNull(varValues(i)) Then
            Coalesce = varValues(i)
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `IsNull()`, `Nz()`, and the data conversion functions are built-in VBA functions and will only slow down your queries in versions prior to 2003.  As far as datatyping goes use `CCur()` to guarantee your data type, but only if you need to do strong comparisons or simply set the format property to Currency on the column.  It is the IF statement that slows things the most, as it adds yet another function to your routine

using this solution: `Nz([Price], CCur(0))`

the only time `CCur()` will execute is when Price Is Null, so overall this is probably the fastest.

The point is that the *least number of total functions used*, the faster your queries will execute.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, my stackoverflow was using an old email account and I can't vote or reply individually to some of the responses because I don't have enough credibility.

Thank you for your posts.  I added a public Function with a return type Double and used 0.00 as a default value.  I called @iDevlop's Coalesce function such that the resulting value in the query is typed. The Nz() function would return the default value of 0.00 as 0 and I would have to multiply it by 1 to make it numeric and Access would then use its formatting.

Being used to sql-server, I missed the Coalesce function and this is really a time saver.  I used Nz everywhere with IIf when it didn't work or if I had multiple values to choose in the query.

So thank you to the contributors on this page.

```
' Use Coalesce instead of Nz and return a double so that it displays correctly.

' If you pass back a 0, it will not be displayed a 0.00 unless you cast it as a fixed(2), or a double, or multiply a Nz returned result times a number.
Public Function CoalesceDbl(dbl As Variant) As Double
    CoalesceDbl = Coalesce(dbl, 0#)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a very old thread, but I was interested to see if anyone had an alternative to `COALESCE`'s multiple arguments. As for an answer to the above, you can use a horribly hacky version like this:

```sql
SELECT 
    CCur("0" & Price)
...
```

The reason this works is because the concatenator (&) foricbly converts `NULL` into an empty string when appending to another value.

This can be used to great effect when you're doing something like appending names and titles together that may contain `NULL` fields. For instance:

```sql
SELECT 
    [SURNAME] & ", " + [Forename] & " (" + [Title] + ")"

/*  └───────┘   └───────────────┘   └──────────────────┘
     Part 1      Part 2              Part 3  */
...
```

This example concatenates all results into a variant string. We then attempt to add (instead of concatenate) a `", "` to the the `[FORENAME]` field. If this field is `NULL` then anything added to a `NULL` is `NULL`. We then attempt to concatenate the result of adding `" ("` and `")"` to the `[TITLE]` field.

Parts 1, 2 and 3 are caluclated first, then concatenated together, resulting at worst in an empty string (not a `NULL` value). This works because concatenation has a lower priority than addition.

I used to use this and the conversion methods quite a bit, years ago. Please be warned that, as highlighted by *@onedaywhen* in the comments to the post by *@pipthegeek*, above, utilising VBA in your queries can make it *sloooow*.

Answer (score -2):

COALESCE or NULLIF function are the standard used on sql server for a good migration to access. ISNULLor IIF or CHOOSE are nonstandard function.