# Union of SQL tables, but only taking the first instance of an ID

Tags: sql, ms-access, duplicates, union

I have three tables with identical columns that I need to union together into one table. Some IDs appear in more than one table, and I need to use the ID from the lowest numbered table first, and ignore that ID in any subsequent tables. Note that only the ID is the same, there aren't any duplicate rows between the tables.

So as an example, these three tables need to be transformed to the final table:

```
**Table 1**
+----+----+----+
| ID | C1 | C2 |
+----+----+----+
| 01 | AA | BB |
| 02 | CC | DD |
| 03 | EE | FF |
+----+----+----+

**Table 2**
+----+----+----+
| ID | C1 | C2 |
+----+----+----+
| 03 | GG | HH |
| 04 | II | JJ |
| 05 | KK | LL |
+----+----+----+

**Table 3**
+----+----+----+
| ID | C1 | C2 |
+----+----+----+
| 01 | MM | NN |
| 04 | OO | PP |
| 06 | QQ | RR |
+----+----+----+

**Resulting Table**
+----+----+----+
| ID | C1 | C2 |
+----+----+----+
| 01 | AA | BB |
| 02 | CC | DD |
| 03 | EE | FF |
| 04 | II | JJ |
| 05 | KK | LL |
| 06 | QQ | RR |
+----+----+----+
```

I have a vague idea of a solution using left joins and 'IS NULL' conditions, but that could get complicated very quickly, especially if the number of tables increases.

Is there a way of specifying duplicates only on one column, not on a whole row?

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: It's T-SQL in Access. I guess another way of phrasing the problem is I want all of Table 1, and then only the rows from table 2 whose IDs don't already exist in Table 1, and then only the rows from table 3 whose IDs don't already exist in Table 1 and Table 2.

Comment: Ooops, I wrote the answer before seeing that you do it in Access... I'll rewrite it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using Access, you can use FIRST function, and I think you only need this:

```
SELECT ID, First(C1) As C1, First(C2) as C2
FROM (
  SELECT * FROM Table1 UNION SELECT * FROM Table2 UNION SELECT * FROM Table3 )
GROUP BY ID
```

Comment: Wow... That is an elegant way of achieving this!

Answer (score 1):

If NULL values don't count, this logic can be applied:

- get all IDs, that exist in the 3 tables (this is the union part)
- left join all the tables, and using COALESCE, find the first non-null value for each column

In <del>Access</del> MS SQL:

```
select ids.ID, COALESCE(t1.C1,t2.C1,t3.C1) C1, COLAESCE(t1.C2,t2.C2,t3.C2) C2 
from
(SELECT ID FROM Table1
UNION
SELECT ID FROM Table2
UNION
SELECT ID FROM Table3) AS ids
left join Table1 t1 on ids.id=t1.id
left join Table2 t2 on ids.id=t2.id
left join Table3 t3 on ids.id=t3.id
```

But Access sadly [doesn't support COALESCE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247858/coalesce-alternative-in-access-sql)... It has NZ:

```
select ids.ID, NZ(NZ(t1.C1,t2.C1),t3.C1) C1, NZ(NZ(t1.C2,t2.C2),t3.C2) C2 
from
(SELECT ID FROM Table1
UNION
SELECT ID FROM Table2
UNION
SELECT ID FROM Table3) AS ids
left join Table1 t1 on ids.id=t1.id
left join Table2 t2 on ids.id=t2.id
left join Table3 t3 on ids.id=t3.id
```

(Though I can't test it not having a MS Access at hand at the moment)

Side note: in Oracle, you could do this (I didn't want to delete it):

```
select ids.ID, NVL(NVL(t1.C1,t2.C1),t3.C1) C1, NVL(NVL(t1.C2,t2.C2),t3.C2) from
(SELECT ID FROM Table1
UNION
SELECT ID FROM Table2
UNION
SELECT ID FROM Table3) ids
left join Table1 t1 on ids.id=t1.id
left join Table2 t2 on ids.id=t2.id
left join Table3 t3 on ids.id=t3.id
```

If however NULL values are considered valid, that is a bit of a problem, as [MS Access doesn't support CASE-WHEN statements](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/advanced/case.php) - unless in VBA...

In Oracle, this would do:

```
select ids.ID,
CASE WHEN t1.ID IS NOT NULL THEN t1.C1 
     WHEN t1.ID IS NULL AND t2.ID IS NOT NULL THEN t2.C1
     ELSE t3.C1 END C1,
CASE WHEN t1.ID IS NOT NULL THEN t1.C2 
     WHEN t1.ID IS NULL AND t2.ID IS NOT NULL THEN t2.C2
     ELSE t3.C2 END C2
from
(SELECT ID FROM Table1
UNION
SELECT ID FROM Table2
UNION
SELECT ID FROM Table3) AS ids
left join Table1 t1 on ids.id=t1.id
left join Table2 t2 on ids.id=t2.id
left join Table3 t3 on ids.id=t3.id
```

Comment: Can't vote up as I don't have enough reputation, whatever that is, but will try it tomorrow and let you know how I get on. Thanks, Null values shouldn't be present so this should work. :)