# SQL select statement with if else condition

Tags: sql, select, if-statement, ms-access-2003

I have a column_a with value, but occasionally it is empty (i.e. NULL), I want to use SQL (Microsoft Access 2003) to access this column and return the column_a value, but it the field does not have a value, I want to pad it with a '0'. The code that I am running is:

```
SQL_string = "SELECT ID, (IF IsNull(column_a) THEN 0, ELSE column_a END IF) ... FROM everything"
```

How can I do it properly?

Answer (score 0):

You want the `nz()` function:

```
select id, nz(column_a, 0)
from . . .
```

Comment: I have tried as you suggested, but NZ function is not available in MS access 2003, it ends up a "NZ" invalid identifier.

Comment: @pckong Seems you're executing the query from outside MS Acess interface? see comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247858/coalesce-alternative-in-access-sql#comment231738_247869

Answer (score 0):

If `Nz()` does not work for you then you can use `IIf()` along with the proper form of `IsNull()` for Access SQL, which is

```vbs
SQL_string = "SELECT ID, IIf(IsNull(column_a), 0, column_a) AS whatever ... FROM everything"
```

Comment: The IFF() function does not work as well. I am running the code on MS Access 2003. It comes out an invalid identifier error. I think it is more of SQL version issue. But thanks for your comments.

Comment: `Iff()` is not valid. The function name is `Iif()`.