# Using Sum function in Left Outer Join

Tags: sql, ms-access, left-join

I have two tables per below:

```
1. DatesMaster

+----------+---------------+
|  m_date  |    capacity   |
+----------+---------------+
| 1/2/2016 |          10   |
| 2/2/2016 |          10   |
| 3/2/2016 |          10   |
+----------+---------------+

2. Schedule

+----------+-------+
| sch_date | qty   |
+----------+-------+
| 1/2/2016 |   2   |
| 1/2/2016 |   2   |
| 1/2/2016 |   2   |
| 2/2/2016 |   5   |
| 2/2/2016 |   5   |
| 3/2/2016 |   5   |
| 3/2/2016 |   1   |
+----------+-------+
```

How do I get the result of `capacity - qty` using left outer join whereby I can display all dates from `DatesMaster` with `Availability` as the difference between `capacity` and sum of `qty` of same dates?

Comment: i am using access in vb.net

Comment: i tried: SELECT DatesMaster.m_date, DatesMaster.capacity - SUM(Schedule.qty) As Balance
FROM DatesMaster
LEFT OUTER JOIN Schedule ON DatesMaster.m_date = Schedule.sch_date GROUP BY DateMaster.m_date

Comment: Have you attempted to resolve the NULLs?

Comment: yes i did and got it right! i used IIf and Is Null and it worked. Nz() did not work.... Thanks a lot for your advise!

Comment: I'm glad I could help.  Remember, if the answer was useful you have the option to [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it.

Comment: just did it. in fact i am new to this platform and new to programming!

Comment: I think you will find this site very valuable on your journey into the world of programming.  Enjoy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any columns in your `SELECT` that are not in the `GROUP BY` must be contained in an aggregate function so you can use `MAX` in this query.

```
SELECT DatesMaster.m_date
    ,MAX(DatesMaster.capacity) - SUM(Schedule.qty) AS Balance
FROM DatesMaster
LEFT JOIN Schedule ON DatesMaster.m_date = Schedule.sch_date
GROUP BY DatesMaster.m_date
```

Or, add the `capacity` column to the `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT DatesMaster.m_date
    ,(DatesMaster.capacity) - SUM(Schedule.qty) AS Balance
FROM DatesMaster
LEFT JOIN Schedule ON DatesMaster.m_date = Schedule.sch_date
GROUP BY DatesMaster.m_date, DatesMaster.capacity
```

Comment: above did not work, got the error: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression 'mdate' as part of an aggregate function.

Comment: in fact my original DatesMaster table contains m_date that are not present in the schedule table.... DatesMaster container dates starting 1-2-2016 till 31-12-2016 where as Schedule has dates 1-2-2016, 2-2-2016 & 3-2-2016 but duplicated....

Comment: In your original query, you had a typo in the `GROUP BY`.  Can you make sure that isn't the cause of the error.  Change `DateMaster.m_date` to `DatesMaster.m_date`.  You were missing an "s".

Comment: You are absolutely right!!! I made a typo.... Thanks a lot!!! Now it is giving me the result in the Balance column but just for the ones matching schedule table... Other DatesMaster.m_date s are being displayed but corresponding Balance is Null whereas logically i want to show DatesMaster.capacity as it is in the table.... (DatesMaster table contains m_date that are not present in the schedule table) Could you advise how to do that?

Comment: For MS Access you can find some possible options here:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/247872/3854195