# Excel as database using SQL Server queries

Tags: sql, excel

I'm trying to run the below query using an Excel Workbook as a data source, but I don't get why the COALESCE function won't work. Is there anything wrong with the query or the COALESCE function doesn't work with Excel?

```
SELECT COALESCE([net value], 0) 
FROM   [sheet1$a1:e6] 
WHERE  [units] = 'UN03' 
UNION ALL 
SELECT COALESCE([net value], 0) 
FROM   [sheet1$a1:e6] 
WHERE  [units] = 'UN06' 
UNION ALL 
SELECT COALESCE([net value], 0) 
FROM   [sheet1$a1:e6] 
WHERE  [units] = 'UN04' 
UNION ALL 
SELECT COALESCE([net value], 0) 
FROM   [sheet1$a1:e6] 
WHERE  [units] = 'UN02' 
UNION ALL 
SELECT COALESCE([net value], 0) 
FROM   [sheet1$a1:e6] 
WHERE  [units] = 'UN01'
```

It seems that the only thing works is the query below, but I can't return the output as the IFF function only accepts values inside single quotes, for example, 'true', 'false'. I'm trying to return these values `sheet1$`.`net value`, '0', the `sheet1$`.`net value` contains the query output and the 0 is an indication the query didn't return anything. Can anyone tell what I'm doing wrong?

```
SELECT IIF(Count(`sheet1$`.`net value`) > 0, `sheet1$`.`net value`, '0') AS 
'Net Value' 
FROM   `sheet1$` `Sheet1$` 
WHERE  ( `sheet1$`.f1 = 'UN03' )
```

[image]

Comment: Which provider are you using: Jet, ACE,...? Have you tried `IFNULL` instead of `COALESCE`?

Comment: COALESCE  is used for lists or multiple columns, if you want to change / check one item, use IsNull, as in 
`SELECT IsNull([net value], 0)`

Comment: Hey Andrew, I'm using Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0. I'd tried IFNULL and ISNULL as well.

Comment: Not sure if this is helpful to mention, but you shouldn't bother to alias a table to its own name: ``sheet1$` `Sheet1$``

Answer (score 0):

You should write the query as though writing for MS Access.  Please reference this, where a number of alternatives are available for your concern:

[coalesce alternative in Access SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247858/coalesce-alternative-in-access-sql)

Comment: Hey @n8, 

I'm using "IIF(Count([net value]) > 0,[net value], 0)," but it just doesn't work.

Comment: If you're doing an aggregate function in the criteria then you need to group by and include the aggregate in the output, like `IIF(Count([net value]) > 0,Count([net value]), 0)`, or don't aggregate like `IIF([net value] > 0,[net value], 0)`.  Mixing those is probably giving you results you don't expect.

Comment: Did you try Nz?

Comment: Hey I'd tried "IIF([net value] > 0,[net value], 0)" before but I'm getting the same result; the zero is not being reeturned.

Comment: What is Nz? Is it another provider?

Comment: Nz is an Access (vba) function ... `Nz ( variant, [ value_if_null ] )`