# How to find the first non null value from different columns in Access?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2013

I am trying to build a query where I can get the first non null id available in multiple columns

So my main table is like this,

| employee id | name | manager |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John |  |
| 2 | Doe |  |
| 3 | Jane |  |
| 4 | Phil |  |
| 5 | Jen |  |

I want to lookup the manager from the following table

| employee id | Manager ID | Senior Manager ID | Director ID | Senior Director ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 21 | 22 | 23 | 24 |
| 2 |  | 22 | 23 | 24 |
| 3 |  |  | 23 | 24 |
| 4 |  |  |  | 24 |
| 5 |  | 22 | 23 | 24 |

And my output should be something like this

| employee id | name | manager |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 21 |
| 2 | Doe | 22 |
| 3 | Jane | 23 |
| 4 | Phil | 24 |
| 5 | Jen | 22 |

So basically, I tried to use this IIF function to do a nested if, and a switch function.
Both didn't return the output that I was expecting.
Thanks!

Edit 1: I tried with Nz, but it works for ManagerID and SeniorManagerID but doesn't work for DirectorID and SeniorDirectorID for some reason.
Meaning, I can get ManagerID and SeniorManagerID, but for the other 2, it returns blank.

Edit 2: I tried to change the query to instead of checking for NULLs, I tried to changed it to empty string, still didn't work.

Comment: I don't use ms_access, but in usual SQL queries, these things will be done using COALESCE. Something like select coalesce (manager_id, senior_manager_id, director_id, senior_director_id) as manager....

Comment: @JonasMetzler, thats true, but unfortunately MS-Access doesn't have COALESCE function.

Comment: Of course, but 1) I think it might help people who have the same question with another DB and 2) I assumed it could help you finding your query. MS Access should provide a similar function, doesn't it? If it really doesn't cover such simple functionality, I wouldn't use it ;)

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no similar function and I am using MS Access as there is a limitation from my organization.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247858/coalesce-alternative-in-access-sql

Comment: Hi, thanks for this, I tried this, but it works for ManagerID and SeniorManagerID but doesn't work for DirectorID and SeniorDirectorID for some reason

Comment: Then these columns probably contain empty strings, not NULL values.

Comment: @Andre, thanks for that, I tried to change the query to reflect empty strings, but sadly didn't work.

Comment: How could that work - missing a right paren at end of the Nz expression.

Comment: If ID fields don't contain null and have empty string then they are not number fields and should be.

Answer (score 2):

The Nz() function is used in Access

```
SELECT Nz(ManagerID, Nz(SeniorManagerID, Nz(DirectorID, Nz(SeniorDirectorID, "None")))) AS Person FROM tablename;
```

Otherwise, would be a much longer expression using IIf() or Switch and IS NULL. More info http://allenbrowne.com/QueryPerfIssue.html#Nz

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. I tried this, but it works for ManagerID and SeniorManagerID but doesn't work for DirectorID and SeniorDirectorID for some reason. I tried to replicate using same logic in excel, it works but for some reason it's not working for SQL.

I also tried Switch and Iif, it is also acting the same way.

Comment: It works for me. You are going to have to be more specific about what "doesn't work" means. Edit your question with attempt.

Comment: I have made the edits in the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Do As following code
You can download link from here
https://www.mediafire.com/file/3s6l9vjtdi4uzau/TestDB.accdb/file

```vb
    Private Sub Command3_Click()
    DoCmd.SetWarnings False
    Dim rs     As DAO.Recordset
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT [employee id], [manager id], [senior manager id], [director id], [senior director id] " & _
        "FROM tblmanagers")
    If Not (rs.EOF And rs.BOF) Then
        rs.MoveFirst
        Do Until rs.EOF = True
            Dim MyManager  As Integer
            If Nz(rs![senior director id] & "") <> vbNullString Then
                MyManager = rs![senior director id]
            End If
            If Nz(rs![director id] & "") <> vbNullString Then
                MyManager = rs![director id]
            End If
            If Nz(rs![senior manager id] & "") <> vbNullString Then
                MyManager = rs![senior manager id]
            End If
            If Nz(rs![manager id] & "") <> vbNullString Then
                MyManager = rs![manager id]
            End If
            CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE tblemployees SET " & _
                              "[employee manager] = " & MyManager & " " & _
                              "WHERE [employee id] = " & rs![employee id] & ""
            rs.MoveNext
        Loop
    Else
    End If
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
End Sub
```

[image]