# Creating an Update Report using Joins in SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, sql-update

I have Sales data in Microsoft Access 2016 that I am trying to update on a weekly basis to show Customer ID, Most Recent Purchase, Order Qty, and Return Qty. As the weeks go by these values can change for any customer so on the Updated Report should show the newest data. Example:

```
TableWeek1
| Customer ID | Purchase Date | Order Qty | Return Qty |
| ----------- | ------------- | --------- | ---------- |
|   1234567   |  01/02/2023   |      1    |      0     |
|   2468135   |  01/03/2023   |      3    |      0     |
|   1357924   |  01/03/2023   |      2    |      0     |
|   3579512   |  01/04/2023   |      2    |      1     |

TableWeek2
| Customer ID | Purchase Date | Order Qty | Return Qty |
| ----------- | ------------- | --------- | ---------- |
|   1234567   |  01/09/2023   |      0    |      1     |
|   2468135   |  01/10/2023   |      0    |      2     |
|   1357924   |  01/11/2023   |      3    |      0     |
|   1597538   |  01/13/2023   |      0    |      2     |
```

I want the result to show:

```
UpdateReport
| Customer ID | Purchase Date | Order Qty | Return Qty | Net Purchase Qty |
| ----------- | ------------- | --------- | ---------- | ---------------- |
|   1234567   |  01/09/2023   |      1    |      1     |         0        |
|   2468135   |  01/10/2023   |      3    |      2     |         1        |
|   1357924   |  01/03/2023   |      5    |      0     |         5        |
|   3579512   |  01/04/2023   |      2    |      1     |         1        |
|   1597538   |  01/13/2023   |      0    |      2     |         -2       |
```

So in the Update Report I have all customers, the latest purchase date, the sum of the order qty, the sum of the return qty, and the difference between the total order and the total return.

I tried

```
SELECT [Customer ID], [Purchase Date], [Order Qty], [Return Qty]
FROM TableWeek1 
FULL JOIN TableWeek2 ON 
TableWeek1.[Customer ID]=TableWeek2.[Customer ID]
```

and was playing with cases to get the results I wanted but they weren't working. What I want is in the Update Report I have all customers, the latest purchase date, the sum of the order qty, the sum of the return qty, and the difference between the total order and the total return.

Comment: Please edit your question and add a tag for the specific type of SQL you're using (MySql, Oracle, MS-SQL, etc)

Comment: Just use aggregation functions (MAX, SUM, etc) and group by customer

Comment: Are you really creating and populating a new table for each week? If so, this is a really bad design pattern - just have a single table and add a “week” column to it if you need to identify which week each row refers to

Comment: @NickW Since the information overrides on a weekly basis and customers can return items, just adding a week column wouldn't catch all the changes I need to catch.

Comment: I may not have been clear - I was talking about the source data that you need to query: is this in one table or is there a separate table for each week? The answer given below, which you seem to think would work, is based on there being a separate source table for each week

Comment: @NickW oh we get separate tables each week in the form of excel workbooks. Since the quantity of rows is too large I can no longer keep the YTD data in excel. I am trying to recreate the processes I do in excel in Access so I can pull analytics from the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting up your example data:

```
create table #TableWeek1
(
    [Customer ID] int,
    [Purchase Date] date,
    [Order Qty] int,
    [Return Qty] int
)

create table #TableWeek2
(
    [Customer ID] int,
    [Purchase Date] date,
    [Order Qty] int,
    [Return Qty] int
)

insert into #TableWeek1 values
(1234567,'01/02/2023',1,0),
(2468135,'01/03/2023',3,0),
(1357924,'01/03/2023',2,0),
(3579512,'01/04/2023',2,1)

insert into #TableWeek2 values
(1234567,'01/09/2023',0 ,1),
(2468135,'01/10/2023',0 ,2),
(1357924,'01/11/2023',3 ,0),
(1597538,'01/13/2023',0 ,2)
```

This query will give your desired output:

```
select
    coalesce(w1.[Customer ID],w2.[Customer ID]) as [Customer ID],
    max(case when isnull(w2.[Purchase Date],'1900-01-01') > isnull(w1.[Purchase Date],'1900-01-01') then w2.[Purchase Date] else w1.[Purchase Date] end) as [Purchase Date],
    sum(isnull(w1.[Order Qty],0)) + sum(isnull(w2.[Order Qty],0)) as [Order Qty],
    sum(isnull(w1.[Return Qty],0)) + sum(isnull(w2.[Return Qty],0)) as [Return Qty],
    (sum(isnull(w1.[Order Qty],0)) + sum(isnull(w2.[Order Qty],0))) - (sum(isnull(w1.[Return Qty],0)) + sum(isnull(w2.[Return Qty],0))) as [Net Purchase Qty]
from 
(
    select [Customer ID] from #TableWeek1
    union
    select [Customer ID] from #TableWeek2
) c
left join #TableWeek1 w1 on c.[Customer ID] = w1.[Customer ID]
left join #TableWeek2 w2 on c.[Customer ID] = w2.[Customer ID]
group by coalesce(w1.[Customer ID],w2.[Customer ID])
```

This assumes that not every `Customer ID` will always appears in both tables, but could be simplified if you know that they in fact would.

Results:

| Customer ID | Purchase Date | Order Qty | Return Qty | Net Purchase Qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234567 | 09/01/2023 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1357924 | 11/01/2023 | 5 | 0 | 5 |
| 1597538 | 13/01/2023 | 0 | 2 | -2 |
| 2468135 | 10/01/2023 | 3 | 2 | 1 |
| 3579512 | 04/01/2023 | 2 | 1 | 1 |

Comment: I see what you did. Thank you very much I will give this a try. Your assumption is correct. The Customer IDs change every week as we get new customers every week, but I was struggling with updating the information for those customers that did show again either for a new purchase or a return. This looks like it should work.

Comment: No problem - if you find the answer helpful, please consider accepting it and/or upvoting it.

Comment: Just tried it with my actual data and received the following error:

Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'max(case when isnull(w2.[Purchase Date],'1900-01-01') > isnull(w1.[Purchase Date],'1900-01-01') then w2.[Purchase Date] else w1.[Purchase Date] end)'.

Comment: For Access SQL you'll need to change several things, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247858/coalesce-alternative-in-access-sql) for a start. Also: parentheses around multiple JOIN expressions.

Comment: Sorry, yes, when I answered, there was no mention of Access in the question or tags, so I answered based on what was there at the time.

Comment: @Andre Thank you for the tip I will check the link out and make changes for what I need.

Comment: @3N1GM4 I apologize. I am new to using SQL and was unaware there would be that drastic of a difference. Thank you anyways for giving me a starting point.

Comment: If you found my answer helpful, please consider accepting and/or upvoting it.